# Is $\frac 3 2$ an upper bound of $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{\{log_2(3/2) \cdot k\}}}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, fractional-part

Let $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow (1, 2)$ be a function with $$f(n) = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{\{log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right) \cdot k\}}}{n}$$ $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the fractional part of x. I want to know if  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: f(n) \leq \frac 3 2$.

Since $\{x\} \in [0, 1) \Rightarrow 2^{\{x\}} \in [1, 2)$ obvious lower and upper bounds for $f(n)$ are $1 \leq f(n) < 2$.
Furthermore, if $\frac 3 2$ is an upper bound for $f(n)$, than it is a sharp bound because $f(1) = \frac 3 2$.
Looking at the Graph it seems that $$ lim_{n\to\infty} f(n) \stackrel{?}{=} \int_0^1 2^{x} dx = \frac{1}{ln(2)} < \frac 3 2$$

While I was unable to show an upper bound of $\frac 3 2$, I had an idea that improved the upper bound to $\frac{46}{27} = 1.\overline{703}$ .
Let $I(k)$ be the interval for possible values of $\{log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right) \cdot k\}$,
$I^*(k) := I(k) \cap \left[1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), 1\right)$ and $I_*(k) := I(k) \cap \left[0, 1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)\right)$.
Let $I(a) \rightarrow I(b) \text{ or } I(b) \leftarrow I(a)$ denote that $I(a)$ influences the possible values of $I(b)$.

**Case 1**: $I^*, I^*, I^*$
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
I^*(k) = \left[1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), 1\right) & \rightarrow & I^*(k+1) = \left[1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)\right) & \rightarrow & I^*(k+2) = \varnothing \\
\end{array}
$$
$\Rightarrow$ There are never three consecutive $I^*$.

**Case 2**: $I^*, I^*, I_*$
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
I^*(k) = \left[1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), 1\right) & \rightarrow & I^*(k+1) = \left[1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)\right) & \rightarrow & I_*(k+2) = \left[0, 2 \cdot log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right) - 1\right) \\
I^*(k) = \left[2 - 2 \cdot log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), 1\right) & \leftarrow & I^*(k+1) = \left[1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)\right) & & I_*(k+2) = \left[0, 2 \cdot log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right) - 1\right) \\
I^*(k) = \left[2 - 2 \cdot log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), 1\right) & & I^*(k+1) = \left[1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)\right) & & I_*(k+2) = \left[0, 2 \cdot log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right) - 1\right) \\
\end{array}
$$
Upper bound of average for three consecutive terms in case 2:
$$\frac{2^{1}+2^{log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)}+2^{2 \cdot log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right) - 1}}{3} = \frac{37}{24} = 1.541\overline{6}$$

**Case 3**: $I_*, I^*, I^*$
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
I_*(k) = \left[0, 1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)\right) & & I^*(k+1) = \left[1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), 1\right) & \rightarrow & I^*(k+2) = \left[1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)\right) \\
I_*(k) = \left[2 - 3 \cdot log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), 1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)\right) & \leftarrow & I^*(k+1) = \left[2 - 2 \cdot log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), 1\right) & \leftarrow & I^*(k+2) = \left[1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)\right) \\
I_*(k) = \left[2 - 3 \cdot log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), 1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)\right) & & I^*(k+1) = \left[2 - 2 \cdot log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), 1\right) & & I^*(k+2) = \left[1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)\right) \\
\end{array}
$$
Upper bound of average for three consecutive terms in case 3:
$$\frac{2^{1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)}+2^{1}+2^{log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)}}{3} = \frac{29}{18} = 1.6\overline{1}$$

**Case 4**: $I^*, I_*, I^*$
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
I^*(k) = \left[1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), 2 - 2 \cdot log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)\right) & \leftarrow & I_*(k+1) = \left[0, 1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)\right) & \rightarrow & I^*(k+2) = \left[log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), 1\right) \\
I^*(k) = \left[1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), 2 - 2 \cdot log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)\right) & & I_*(k+1) = \left[0, 1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)\right) & & I^*(k+2) = \left[log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right), 1\right) \\
\end{array}
$$
Upper bound of average for three consecutive terms in case 4:
$$\frac{2^{2 - 2 \cdot log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)}+2^{1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)}+2^{1}}{3} = \frac{46}{27} = 1.\overline{703}$$

**Case 5, 6, & 7**: $I_*, I_*, I^* / I^*, I_*, I_* / I_*, I^*, I_*$
Upper bound of average for three consecutive terms in case 5, 6 & 7:
$$\frac{2^{1}+2^{1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)}+2^{1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)}}{3} = \frac{14}{9} = 1.\overline{5}$$

**Case 8**: $I_*, I_*, I_*$
Upper bound of average for three consecutive terms in case 8:
$$\frac{2^{1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)}+2^{1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)}+2^{1 - log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)}}{3} = \frac{4}{3} = 1.\overline{3}$$

$\Longrightarrow$ the average of every three consecutive terms is smaller than $\frac{46}{27}$, $f(1) = \frac 3 2 = 1.5 \text{ and } f(2) = \frac{21}{16} = 1.3125 \Rightarrow \forall n \in \mathbb{N}:f(n) < \frac{46}{27}. \quad \Box$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $\frac 3 2$ is an upper bound for $f(n)$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Let $c := log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)$.
I expanded on the idea of possible intervals a little more starting from the intervals $\left[0, 1-c\right)$, $\left[1-c, c\right)$ and $\left[c, 1\right)$.
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
I(k) \in \left[0, 1-c\right) & \rightarrow & I(k+1) \in \left[c, 1\right)\\
I(k) \in \left[1-c, c\right) & \rightarrow & I(k+1) \in \left[0, 1-c\right)\\
I(k) \in \left[c, 1\right) & \rightarrow & I(k+1) \in \left[0, 1-c\right) \cup \left[1-c, c\right)\\
\end{array}
$$
I then repeatedly split the intervals that either have two target intervals or are targeted by two intervals, resulting in the following cycle of possible intervals with two paths.

[image: Cycle of possible intervals]

Upper bound of the arithmetic mean (longer path cycle):

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{2^{3-4c}+2^{2-3c}+2^{2-2c}+2^{1-c}+2^{1}+2^{c}+2^{2c-1}+2^{3c-1}+2^{4c-2}+2^{5c-2}+2^{6c-3}+2^{7c-4}+2^{6-9c}+2^{5-8c}+2^{5-7c}+2^{4-6c}+2^{3-5c}}{17} = \frac{1011366493}{685283328} \approx 1.476\\
\end{array}
$$

Upper bound of the arithmetic mean (shorter path cycle):

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{2^{3-4c}+2^{2-3c}+2^{2-2c}+2^{8-13c}+2^{8-12c}+2^{7-11c}+2^{6-10c}+2^{6-9c}+2^{5-8c}+2^{5-7c}+2^{4-6c}+2^{3-5c}}{12} = \frac{7041236}{4782969} \approx 1.472\\
\end{array}
$$

The first thirteen terms of $f(n)$:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|ccccccccccccc|}
\hline
n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13\\
\hline
2^{\left\{log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right) \cdot n\right\}} & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{9}{8} & \frac{27}{16} & \frac{81}{64} & \frac{243}{128} & \frac{729}{512} & \frac{2187}{2048} & \frac{6561}{4096} & \frac{19683}{16384} & \frac{59049}{32768} & \frac{177147}{131072} & \frac{531441}{524288} & \frac{1594323}{1048576}\\
\hline
\Sigma & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{21}{8} & \frac{69}{16} & \frac{357}{64} & \frac{957}{128} & \frac{4557}{512} & \frac{20415}{2048} & \frac{47391}{4096} & \frac{209247}{16384} & \frac{477543}{32768} & \frac{2087319}{131072} & \frac{8880717}{524288} & \frac{19355757}{1048576}\\
\hline
f(n) & \frac {3}{2} & \frac{21}{16} & \frac{23}{16} & \frac{357}{256} & \frac{957}{640} & \frac{1519}{1024} & \frac{20415}{14336} & \frac{47391}{32768} & \frac{69749}{49152} & \frac{477543}{327680} & \frac{2087319}{1441792} & \frac{2960239}{2097152} & \frac{19355757}{13631488}\\
\hline
\approx & 1.500 & 1.313 & 1.438 & 1.395 & 1.495 & 1.483 & 1.424 & 1.446 & 1.419 & 1.457 & 1.448 & 1.412 & 1.420\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
So starting at the interval $\left[2 \cdot log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right) - 1, 2 - 3 \cdot log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)\right)$ with a value of $max\left(\frac{1011366493}{685283328}, \frac{7041236}{4782969}, \frac{19355757}{13631488}\right) = \frac{1011366493}{685283328} \approx 1.476$ and assuming 13 previous terms we check both the short and long cycle for one round using the upper bound of each interval. If all resulting values are $\leq \frac 3 2$ then the upper bound of $f(n)$ is $\frac 3 2$ since further rounds always start at or below the arithmetic mean of the longer cycle and reduce the deviation from the mean.
Let $C^*(n)$ be the upper bound of an interval in the longer cycle and let $C_*(n)$ be the upper bound of an interval in the shorter cycle (both starting with $C^*(14) = C_*(14) = 2 - 3 \cdot log_2\left(\frac 3 2\right)$).
Longer cycle:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|cccccccccccccccccc|}
\hline
n & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30\\
\hline
2^{C^*(n)} & \mathbf{-} & \frac{32}{27} & \frac{16}{9} & \frac{4}{3} & 2 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{9}{8} & \frac{27}{16} & \frac{81}{64} & \frac{243}{128} & \frac{729}{512} & \frac{2187}{2048} & \frac{32768}{19683} & \frac{8192}{6561} & \frac{4096}{2187} & \frac{1024}{729} & \frac{256}{243} & \frac{128}{81}\\
\hline
\Sigma & \frac{13147764409}{685283328} & \frac{13959952057}{685283328} & \frac{15178233529}{685283328} & \frac{16091944633}{685283328} & \frac{17462511289}{685283328} & \frac{18490436281}{685283328} & \frac{19261380025}{685283328} & \frac{20417795641}{685283328} & \frac{21285107353}{685283328} & \frac{22586074921}{685283328} & \frac{23561800597}{685283328} & \frac{12146797427}{342641664} & \frac{4239074257}{114213888} & \frac{4381680593}{114213888} & \frac{4595590097}{114213888} & \frac{4756022225}{114213888} & \frac{4876346321}{114213888} & \frac{5056832465}{114213888}\\
\hline
f(n) & \frac{1011366493}{685283328} & \frac{13959952057}{9593966592} & \frac{15178233529}{10279249920} & \frac{16091944633}{10964533248} & \frac{17462511289}{11649816576} & \frac{18490436281}{12335099904} & \frac{19261380025}{13020383232} & \frac{20417795641}{13705666560} & \frac{21285107353}{14390949888} & \frac{22586074921}{15076233216} & \frac{23561800597}{15761516544} & \frac{12146797427}{8223399936} & \frac{4239074257}{2855347200} & \frac{4381680593}{2969561088} & \frac{4595590097}{3083774976} & \frac{4756022225}{3197988864} & \frac{4876346321}{3312202752} & \frac{1011366493}{685283328}\\
\hline
\approx & 1.476 & 1.455 & 1.477 & 1.468 & 1.499 & 1.499 & 1.479 & 1.490 & 1.479 & 1.498 & 1.495 & 1.477 & 1.485 & 1.476 & 1.490 & 1.487 & 1.472 & 1.476\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
Shorter cycle:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|ccccccccccccc|}
\hline
n & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25\\
\hline
2^{C_*(n)} & \mathbf{-} & \frac{32}{27} & \frac{16}{9} & \frac{2097152}{1594323} & \frac{1048576}{531441} & \frac{262144}{177147} & \frac{65536}{59049} & \frac{32768}{19683} & \frac{8192}{6561} & \frac{4096}{2187} & \frac{1024}{729} & \frac{256}{243} & \frac{128}{81}\\
\hline
\Sigma & \frac{13147764409}{685283328} & \frac{13959952057}{685283328} & \frac{15178233529}{685283328} & \frac{1302451359881}{55507949568} & \frac{1411973025929}{55507949568} & \frac{1494114275465}{55507949568} & \frac{1555720212617}{55507949568} & \frac{1648129118345}{55507949568} & \frac{1717435797641}{55507949568} & \frac{1821395816585}{55507949568} & \frac{1899365830793}{55507949568} & \frac{1957843341449}{55507949568} & \frac{2045559607433}{55507949568}\\
\hline
f(n) & \frac{1011366493}{685283328} & \frac{13959952057}{9593966592} & \frac{15178233529}{10279249920} & \frac{1302451359881}{888127193088} & \frac{1411973025929}{943635142656} & \frac{1494114275465}{999143092224} & \frac{1555720212617}{1054651041792} & \frac{329625823669}{222031798272} & \frac{1717435797641}{1165666940928} & \frac{1821395816585}{1221174890496} & \frac{1899365830793}{1276682840064} & \frac{1957843341449}{1332190789632} & \frac{2045559607433}{1387698739200}\\
\hline
\approx & 1.476 & 1.455 & 1.477 & 1.467 & 1.496 & 1.495 & 1.475 & 1.485 & 1.473 & 1.492 & 1.488 & 1.470 & 1.474\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
$\Rightarrow \frac 3 2$ is an upper bound for $f(n)$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\text{.} \quad \Box$